# Mysql equivalent of MS-Sql server IDENTITY field

Tags: mysql

I have a sql-server query and i want to run it (or create an equivalent query) on mysql. But currently i'm getting syntax error. Can anyone help me to create a mysql equivalent of the below mentioned sql-server query?

```
create table Emp(EmpName varchar(20) not null,keyword varchar(20) not null,
DOB datetime not null,Comments text(65535),EmpId int primary key IDENTITY(1,1));
```

Following is the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTITY(1,1))' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be defined as auto_incremented primary key instead. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp (
  EmpId     INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  EmpName   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
  KEYWORD   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  DOB       DATETIME    NOT NULL,
  Comments  TEXT(65535),
  PRIMARY KEY (EmpId)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Emp (
  EmpId     INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  EmpName   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  KEYWORD   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
  DOB       DATETIME    NOT NULL, 
  Comments  TEXT(65535),  PRIMARY KEY (EmpId)
);
```

You can use auto_increment .By default it will increase by 1.If you want any other increment you can specify your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [auto-increment field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)